# Sklearn probability different inside function

Tags: python, function, scikit-learn

I am trying to understand why the output from sklearn prediction is different when put inside a function.

I have a naive bayes classifier trained for text and when I make my predictions like this

```
examples = ['my favorite sport is probably baseball']
predictions = vec_clf.predict(examples)[0]
probs = vec_clf.predict_proba(examples)
m = np.max(probs)

print predictions,m
```

I get the right prediction result. However if I write a function to do this

```
def classify(input):

    predictions = vec_clf.predict(input)[0]
    probs = vec_clf.predict_proba(input)
    m = np.max(probs)

    return predictions,m

classify('my favorite sport is probably baseball')
```

It returns a completely different and very wrong result with different confidence and class label. Why would it do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first attempt, you are passing a *list of strings* to `model.predict_proba` and `model.predict` (which is what is expected), in the latter attempt, you are passing a single string. Instead, pass a *list of strings*:

```
classify(['my favorite sport is probably baseball'])
```

Or wrap `input` in a list inside your function:

```
def classify(input):
    input = [input]
    predictions = vec_clf.predict(input)[0]
    probs = vec_clf.predict_proba(input)
    m = np.max(probs)

    return predictions,m
```

What is going on when you only pass a string is that each individual character is being interpreted as a document. So, try just doing:

```
vec_clf.predict('my favorite sport is probably baseball')
```

To better see what is going on.